# Snow Leopard instant Kernel Panic, no boot

Tags: macos, mac, kernel-panic

While downloading a program called "multibeast" in Snow Leopard, the machine crashed. The only part of the program I loaded was the kext & enablers files. Now, my Mac crashes without booting. Tried a recovery reinstall of the OS, no good. I tried to start in verbose, safe mode, single mode. Still crashes. Kernel panic. I think the boot.efi is corrupted but not sure. This machine still boots fine in Lion and El Capitan, but I need to run S.L. for some of the software. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Multibeats is for post-installation on Hackintosh. It won't really work on real Mac, as it is already set up to work with the Hardware.

If you know what files were changed, you could boot into another OS and undo the changes.

Worst Case, you can back up the files (with another OS) and reinstall Snow Leopard. (Other OS must support mounting and reading HFS+. Examples: Other OS X installation, Linux with hfs+ support installed)